# Java - ¿Cómo destruir/cerrar por completo un JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

**Estoy haciendo un programa que maneja dos JFrame** *(Sé que no es recomendable usar más de uno; pero bueno)* **y hago pasar de uno a otro,** y al hacerlo, que desaparesca el anterior. Pero aquí viene el asunto:
Yo **utiliso el clásico setVisible() para hacer que el anterior JFrame desaparezca, pero creo que este comando solo lo oculta;** y entonces, el JFrame cerrado, sigue por ahí ocupando algo de memoria. **¿Cómo lo cierro de tal modo que ya no exista, que quede destruido, que no ocupe memoria, que no solo se oculte?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos, Sunny.

Sí, como mencionas, el método `setVisible(false);` sólo ocultará la ventana mientras se ejecuta tu aplicación.

Existe un método llamado `tuVentana.dispose();` que permitirá hacer lo que pides, según la documentación de Java:

> Libera todos los recursos de pantalla nativos utilizados por esta ventana, sus subcomponentes y todos sus hijos propios. Es decir, los recursos para estos componentes se destruirán, cualquier memoria que consuman se devolverá al sistema operativo y se marcarán como no reproducibles.

fuente: [Documentación de java para clase Window](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose())

Además, también se menciona que si la última ventana reproducible (esto es, que pueda mostrarse), se cierra por medio de un `dispose`, la aplicación se cerrará.