# Borrar una ventana que queda atrás de otra cuando abres una nueva?

Tags: java, netbeans

hola buenas tengo un programa que tiene un menú principal y 3 ventanas diferentes, pero me molesta que al darle regresar a una de las ventanas secundarias para volver al menú principal la ventana secundaria siga abierta y solo se oculte atrás y así sucesivamente si se siguen abriendo mas.**USO NETBEANS**

```
 Vivienda newframe = new Vivienda();

        newframe.setVisible(true);

        this.disable();
```

este es uno de mis codigos para abrir una de las ventanas secuendarias desde la ventana del menu principal pero nose como hacer para que al regresar de la ventana secundarias no se acumulen, sino que solo quede la ultima que se debe mostrar en pantalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando estas en una ventana secundaria y le das a regresar, entiendo que es dándole a un botón, quieres que desaparezca. Pues bien es bastante sencillo solo tienes que poner el action listener de ese boton setVisible(false)
Esto sería el action listener del boton

```
    botonRegresar.addActionListener(new regresar());
```

y aqui la declaración de la classe regresar

```
class regregar implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // si este boton tiene que hacer operaciones o cualquier cosa pues lo hacer aqui
        // Y caundo haya terminado con todo y haya salido bien pues escondes la ventana
        setVisible(false);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad que me ayudaste, te lo agradesco que tengas un buen dia

Comment: Siendo más purista: esto no "borra" la ventana, sino que la oculta. Si se necesita destruir a esa ventana y liberar memoria, [se utiliza `dispose()`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129658).